# if statements and sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am attempting change the menu accordingly if the user is logged in or not. It keeps on coming up with this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp2\htdocs\JobBoard\menu.php on line 3
menu.php

```
<?php

$useremail = $_SESSION['login_user'];

if($useremail==NULL)
{
 $loggedinout='<div id="menulogin"><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a href="login.php">Login</a> &nbsp </div>';
 }
 else
 $loggedinout='<div id="menulogin"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a> &nbsp </div>';

echo'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/menu.css" />
<div id="menucontainer">' . $loggedinout . '<div id="menulogo"><img src="images/logo.png" /></div>
<div id="searchmenu"></div>
'
?>
```

This is my page whwere I start the session
login.php

```
<?php
include 'menu.php';
include 'db_connect.php';
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// email and password sent from Form 
$myemail=addslashes($_POST['email']); 
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']); 

$sql="SELECT userID FROM users WHERE email='$myemail' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myemail and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
session_register("myemail");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myemail;

header("location: index2.php");
}
else 
{
$error="location: test.php";
}
}
?>
```

I'm sure it's quite an easy thing for someone. Please help

Comment: Incidentally, `addslashes` is not the correct function to escape SQL input with. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Also note that the [old `mysql_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) are deprecated, and [you should move to MySQLi or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). If you do, you also have the option of using *parameterised queries* rather than manually escaping your input values.

Answer (score 4):

You have `include 'menu.php';` **before** `session_start()`. PHP runs through in order, so when the `include` happens, the session hasn't been started yet.

Try putting the `session_start()` at the very beginning of the file instead:

```
session_start();
include 'menu.php';
include 'db_connect.php';
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: login_user in C:\xampp2\htdocs\JobBoard\menu.php on line 2
Notice: Undefined index: active in C:\xampp2\htdocs\JobBoard\login.php on line 21
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_register() in C:\xampp2\htdocs\JobBoard\login.php on line 28

Comment: Those are now appearing have no idea what they mean

Comment: @NaivenDhali Well, the first two mean that you're trying to read from a variable that you've never written to yet; they're just notices, not errors, but you could use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to check first. The last one is because [the `session_register()` function was removed in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/session_register), because it was replaced years ago by just adding your values to `$_SESSION`.